# Unable to create new DataWindows in Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow, powerbuilder-2019

I'm currently running PowerBuilder 2019 R2 Build 2328.  Previously I had no issues creating new DataWindows, but now when I try to create, nothing happens.  I can open existing datawindows, make copies of datawindows, create new objects that are not datawindows(i.e. windows), but I can't create a new datawindow.  I go to File --> New--> Select any datawindow and click 'OK', and the window closes without any error and no datawindow.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you open the database painter?

Comment: Restart the computer?  If that fails reinstall PowerBuilder.  Sometimes if you have multiple monitors, PowerBuilder can get messed up where an object is open but you can't see it; when that happens I unplug my 2nd monitor, or temporarily change resolution to trigger PB to repaint, but the issue you are describing seems different so I don't know.